# Foreach loop, with tons of vars

Tags: php

I have a bunch of text in a database, which is id'ed by "grp" how would i get to bind each text to "example :

```
if($grp->$grp === '1') {
---> $text+$grp->$grp <--- = $grp->text
}
```

Is it possible to do a foreach & while loop, that binds the text to each "text1, text2 etc" ?

I've tried this way

```
foreach ($getgrouptxt as $grp) {
 $grpnr = $grp->grp;
  while ($grpnr < '63') {
   $text+$grpnr = $grp->text;}
}
}
```

So basicly
Getting text from an array, using foreach looping through everyone of them

I want it to set the text var ($text"number") to 
$grp-text, each time it hits a number until 62 is reached

Comment: Is there any reason why you need a dynamically named variable (i.e. `$test$grpnr`) instead of an array (which is the correct representation in most cases) (`$test[$grpnr]`)?

Comment: No not really. how would you suggest i did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### + is for numeric addition

You intend to append a number to a string, but you are using the numeric addition operator (`+`) instead of string concatenation operator (`.`). So, instead of `$text+$grpnr` you need `$text.$grpnr`

### If you want to assign a value, the variable which will hold it is at the left-hand side of the assignment

If you want to store `$text.$grpnr` into `$grp->text`, then you need to invert the assignment:

```
$grp->text = $text.$grpnr;
```

### If you want to use a dynamic variable name, then use {} around it

If `$text.$grpnr` should be a variable name and you intend to store `$grp->text` into it, then:

```
{$text.$grpnr} = $grp->text;
```

This will not work in PHP 5 though.

### Beware comparing numbers as strings

'7' < '63'

is `false`, because PHP will do a textual comparison and '7' is behind '6' in the alphabet. If you want to use numeric comparisons, compare to 63 and convert `$grpnr` to a numeric type if it is textual.

### Suggestion

According to the best of my understanding of your problem, you need something like

```
foreach ($getgrouptxt as $grp) {
    $grpnr = $grp->grp;
    while (((int)$grpnr) < 63) {
        $grp->text = $text.$grpnr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the {} advice. Managed to do fix it by doing the following `foreach($grptxt as $key => $value) {
   if($key < '63') {
    ${"text".$key} = $value;
   }
  } `

Comment: @MilboDoe you are welcome. If this answer helped you solve the problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Your answer will be accepteded, as correct answer, however i went around the Array way of doing it. `foreach ($getgrouptxt as $grps){
    $grpnr = $grps->grp;
    $text = $grps->text;
    array_push($grptxt[$grpnr]=$text);
   } `

Comment: @MilboDoe thanks. Your new code no longer compares to 63. Is this good in your case?